# Different value printed on Java Crystal Reports

Tags: java, swing, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am having a problem with my java program trying to print my crystal report. I generated a preview of the report on the crystal report editor and the value says 11.80 as seen on the picture.

[image: Original Preview from Crystal Report Editor]
Then, I tried to preview the report from my java program which only just call the report and display it on a jpanel, I got a 12.20 as a result. How is that possible? Nothing has been modified in the report programatically upon preview aside from the database tables ( which points out to a single database) but it yields a different result. I'm using crystal reports xi.

[image]

Comment: One of your assumptions (e.g. same report, same database, etc.) is wrong.

Comment: No, Im pretty sure about that. Whenever I do changes on the report, the java program reflects the changes. And also we are only working on one database.

Comment: You are at least looking at different years, the top screenshot is 2012 and the bottom is 2011.  Pretty much all of the data is different between the two of them.

Comment: actually it shows identical reports. other values are just the same except that one single record. Same report, same tables used, and same parameters, but different result. Im guessing it might be how the report was processed once it enters the java jar files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. Not sure what happened, but after a couple of report editing, they arrived on the same answer.